# Different target positions when using different view sizes with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, objectanimator

I am trying to implement an animation where I create an copy of an `ImageView`, shrink it and move it to the position of another view along a curve. The goal is that the view disappears when it reaches the position of the target view. My animation code is as follows (code simplified for this question):

```
fun animate(imageViewToCopy: ImageView, targetView: ImageView) {
    // create copy of ImageView
    val copy = imageViewToCopy.createCopy()
    // draw it on the decor view (params excluded, from example code)
    activity.window.decorView.addView(copy)
    startAnimation(copy, targetView)
}

private fun startAnimation(imageView: ImageView, targetView: ImageView) {

    val dest = IntArray(2)
    targetView.getLocationOnScreen(dest)

    val targetX = dest[0]
    val targetY = dest[1]

    val disappearAnimatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.SCALE_Y, 1f, 0f)
    val disappearAnimatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.SCALE_X, 1f, 0f)
    val translatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.Y, targetY.toFloat())
    val translatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.X, targetX.toFloat())
    translatorX.interpolator = TimeInterpolator { input ->
        // create curve
        (-Math.pow((input - 1).toDouble(), 2.0) + 1f).toFloat()
    }

    AnimatorSet().apply {
        playSequentially(disappearAnimatorX, disappearAnimatorY, translatorX, translatorY)
        duration = 1000L          
        start()
    }
}
```

The problem is that the size of the `ImageView` that I'm animating changes the position where it ends up. So when I use a small one it ends up at the bottom right of the target view, but when the `ImageView` is bigger it ends up somewhere out of the screen. I would expect that the size doesn't matter and the view just shrinks faster and ends up at the same spot regardless. The `targetX` and `targetY` is the same for each image size so i figure that's not the problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: why dont you use `android.transition.Scene`s? more: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html

Comment: I have to dynamically animate an `ImageView` from a `RecyclerView` from a `Fragment` onto a view in my `BottomNavivationView`, which is placed in the outer `Activity`. Not sure how that can be achieved with `Scenes`.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions or / and http://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition

Comment: There is no `Intent` being fired, so no shared element transition. The fragment is inflated inside the `Activity`. I am trying to move a `View` on the decor view independently of any `Activity`/`Fragment`.

Comment: i though that `"outer Activity"`is a separate `Activity` you are starting, so if transitions are to be applied inside the same activity the first link is valid

Comment: Let me clarify. There is a `Fragment` that is inflated in an `Activity`. The Fragment has an `RecyclerView` with dynamic views with an `ImageView` inside each item. When a cell is clicked, that `ImageView` has to be copied on top of the existing `ImageView` and animated to an absolute position in the layout of the outer `Activity`. If this can be achieved with `Scenes` i'll get back to you, but I doubt it.

Comment: ok if you dont want to use `TransitionManager` try setting pivot x/y to 0 (`View#setPivotX/Y`), default is center of the view and this could make some problems when scaling and translating